# jQuery UI droppable question

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, droppable

I am in a final stage of getting my app ready and am stuck on a couple of items.

1. When an item is dragged from left column into main area it needs to create a new group box, which it does OK. But if I drag another item into this newly created box, instead of staying there it creates another new box...
2. I drag items into pre-defined boxes. Then I decide to create a new box by dragging an item from pre=defined box into the yellow area. It does not, but floats back into the box. It must be able to create a new box whether it is dragged from the left column or from any other box in the main area.

Would appreciate a fresh pair of eyes taking a look at it and letting me know what am I missing here.

Comment: Can't access your test page. It's protected by a password.

Comment: Can you try calling `$("#dropZone").droppable({` before the initial calls to `createStack`?  I'm curious if the difference between the static ones and the dynamic is that `droppable` has already been called when the new one is created.  Additionally, have you tried calling the dynamically added ones with `creator = true` just to eliminate that as the problem?

Comment: So sorry, tested something else and left password enabled. Should be cleared now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is solved if you set the [`greedy`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#option-greedy) option of `newStack` droppable to `true`. This prevents `drop` events to propagate to other container droppables like, in your case, `#dropZone`, that was creating a new stack:

```
newStack.droppable({
    tolerance: "intersect",
    accept: ".card",
--> greedy: true,  <--
    drop: function(event, ui) {
            card = ui.draggable;
            putCardIntoStack(card,stackId);
    }
});
```

The second problem is solved if you change the `accept` option of `#dropZone` droppable just to `.card`.
This is because cards on stacks have the class name `stackcard`, which surely makes the function return `false`:

```
$("#dropZone").droppable({
    /*accept: '.card', function(dropElem) {
                return (!dropElem.hasClass("stackcard"));
    },*/
--> accept: '.card' <--
    ...
```

Comment: @santa, There's a problem in ``createEmptyStack`` server code. It's always returning an empty string as id.

Comment: Oh, you're good. Yes, I added some code today that obstructed some of my older code from creating the groups properly. I removed it and now I can create multiple boxes, but for some reason I can't move items from block to block. Man, this never stops...

Comment: I think I got it! Part of the same problem -- I was using an creator ID. Not that it's fixed, how do I make my draggable items to be always on top? I even tried adding z-index:9999, but the stacks seem to be always above... weird.